# Process hash and redirect to controller based on parameter value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following parameters being passed to a controller. How can i process this.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "_method"=>"put",
  "authenticity_token"=>"PG7U0PkCb1LViWkUWNV0lKuPWfVKM/Kl4T+zW4Eaaq8=",
  "campaign"=>{"2"=>{"status"=>"Approved",
  "notes"=>""},
  "1"=>{"status"=>"Approved",
  "notes"=>""}},
  "Commit"=>"Process"}
```

My intention is to extract each campaign, read the status and redirect that record to a reject and approve controller depending on their contents.

Comment: Have tried each but unrecognised. When output params[:campaign] i get `{"2"=>{"status"=>"Approved", "notes"=>""}, "1"=>{"status"=>"Approved", "notes"=>""}}`. Dont know how to proceed to be honest.

Comment: Got this far now in terms of testing 
    `params[:campaign].each do |key, array|
      if array[:status] == "Approved"
        puts "#{key} is #{array[:status]}"
      end
    end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like this?

```
params['campaign'].each do |id, attributes|
  puts "Campaign id equals #{id} and status is #{attributes['status']}"
  # Campaign.find(id).update(attributes)

  if attributes['status'] == 'Approved'
    reirect_to approved_campaign_path id
  else
    reirect_to rejected_campaign_path id
  end
end
```

Comment: While I was waiting I actually wrote this `def process_campaign
    authorize! :operator, current_user.operator
    params[:campaign].each do |key, array|
      if array[:status] == "Approved"
        redirect_to new_operator_applied_campaign_path(:campaign_id => key)
      elsif array[:status] == "Rejected"
        redirect_to reject_operator_campaign_path(key), campaign_name: key
      end
    end
    redirect_to operator_campaigns_path
  end`

So yeah I think you'll get the tick as you have such a brilliant mind...just like me. Thanks though.

Comment: Redirect_to is failing for this as it is performing a GET rather than POST. Any suggestions. I'm reading that redirect_to doesnt work with POST so need another solution.

Comment: You can try to send request via AJAX and use javascript to redirect user to proper page.

Comment: Actually added `:status => 307` which seemed to do the trick but thanks for the input.